# R: Assign group value based on first occurence

Tags: r, grouping, data-manipulation

I want to assign sequential group value (1-n) based on the first occurence of "Accident" in Events column. So everything from the start til first accident, including the Accident itself would be Group 1. Same principle would be applied to next groups. Do you know how can I achieve this in R? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do the `lag` of the logical expression and get the cumulative sum

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Group = cumsum(lag(Events == "Accident", default = TRUE)))
#     Events Group
#1         A     1
#2         A     1
#3         A     1
#4         B     1
#5         C     1
#6         A     1
#7         C     1
#8         B     1
#9  Accident     1
#10        C     2
#11        C     2
#12        C     2
#13        B     2
#14        A     2
#15 Accident     2
#16        C     3
#17        A     3
#18        A     3
#19        B     3
#20        B     3
#21 Accident     3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Events = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "A", "C", 
"B", "Accident", "C", "C", "C", "B", "A", "Accident", "C", "A", 
 "A", "B", "B", "Accident")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```